# Custom filter attrbiute access RoleManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I want to build a custom filter attribute that inherits `AuthorizeAttribute`.

In a normal MVC controller I can do like this:

```
private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }

        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
```

How can I access the RoleManager in the custom attribute?

Comment: Is this a property inside your controller? Please provide the controller with its namespace

Comment: Yes this is a property in a controller, the controller name and namespace is irrelevant as this is a custom attribute filter. All I wanted was to create the same property within the filter itself, the only thing is that in the controller is `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` ... in the filter attribute I have to do it within `AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)` and then I can just do `var roleManager = httpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();` and it will work.

Comment: Ok I meant you want to be able to access the controller property from your filter-attribute. So you solved your problem?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the AuthorizeCore method of the AuthorizeAttribute class which you are ineriting? protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var roleManager = httpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }